# Testing intersection of rotated CGRects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, math, cgrect

I have two CGRects, one of which is rotated. I need someway of detecting when they collide. CGRectIntersectsRect does not work for this, since it assumes they are not rotated. Is there anyway to go about doing this?

Comment: Can't you create a new `CGRect` representing the rotated rectangle and test using that?

Comment: If you're testing with `frame` and not `bounds`, then of course you'll get false positives.  Bounds takes into account transformation, and can be converted to and from the coordinates of some common superview with the `convertRect:to/fromView:` method

Comment: @CarlNorum The problem is that CGRect does not store rotation it only contains a point and a size, so it would do no good to create a new rect.

Comment: @MartinR, Thank you I will look at that and respond on if it works or not.

Comment: I think I get it - you mean arbitrary rotations, not just 90 degrees.  I was misunderstanding.

Comment: @CodaFi, Thanks. But the issue is the same as above. Converting to a different rect does not help solve the issue that CGRectIntersectsRect does not expect a rotated rect.